# Keep rows hidden and show when search

Tags: javascript

good day,
I'm using a dynamic table that works perfectly fine but it became to long and the interface became slow.

I see many many tutorials regarding dynamic search in tables BUT in none of the cases the rows are hidden and then appear while searching, it is always the list / rows that are being reduced to the keyword.

Does anyone have any idea, document or old posts (I really did not find), to indicate to give me an idea how to do?

Thanks in advance!!

```
        <table class="0" id="demo" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="left">From</th>
                <th align="left">Destination</th>
                <th align="left">Road Distance (km)</th>
                <th align="left">By Air (hrs)</th>
                <th align="left">By Rail (hrs)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Sydney</strong></td>
                <td>Adelaide</td>
                <td>1412</td>
                <td>1.4</td>
                <td>25.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Sydney</strong></td>
                <td>Brisbane</td>
                <td>982</td>
                <td>1.5</td>
                <td>16</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Sydney</strong></td>
                <td>Canberra</td>
                <td>286</td>
                <td>.6</td>
                <td>4.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Sydney</strong></td>
                <td>Melbourne</td>
                <td>872</td>
                <td>1.1</td>
                <td>10.5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Adelaide</strong></td>
                <td>Perth</td>
                <td>2781</td>
                <td>3.1</td>
                <td>38</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Adelaide</strong></td>
                <td>Alice Springs</td>
                <td>1533</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>20.25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Adelaide</strong></td>
                <td>Brisbane</td>
                <td>2045</td>
                <td>2.15</td>
                <td>40</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> <br><br>
<!-- TABLE FILTER -->
```

`<script src="tablefilter.js"></script>
<script src="test-alternate-rows.js"></script>`

Comment: Just do the reverse hide them in css or style="display: none" and on search instead of hide use show.

Comment: The idea would be a BLANK table that have the rows appearing according to the Search.

Comment: Doing like this, it initially hides nicely as I intend to do, but when I clean the results all the table appears:

<tr style="display: none">
                    <td><strong>Sydney</strong></td>
                    <td>Adelaide</td>
                    <td>1412</td>
                    <td>1.4</td>
                    <td>25.3</td>

Comment: you need to add a case that will hide all rows when search is empty. but you can have problems with small number of characters like 2 of them. It will show lot of rows. Why don't you don't pick working solution like data table that have search + pagination? If you want to do this yourself then you can try to add pagination with search.

Comment: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Excellent idea. It would solve the overload problem. Thanks!